# Debugging mobile webapp using iPad?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, ipad, web-applications, safari

Some of my AngularJS components are not displayed in Safari on iPad. Is there any way to debug it? All I have is Windows PC and iPad.

In addition, website is displayed properly in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and adroid devices. Gotta fix the issue, but as far I know, Mac is necessery to debug safari. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) ? you can run that command line tool while connecting the ios device to windows machine, Then you can debug the ios browser(may be chrome/ not remember safari is working for that) from the desktop chrome developer tools. I found that is the only easy way to do it. Also if this couldn't work, just try to find some other repositories of this same debug-proxy.
eg. [ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32](https://github.com/artygus/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32/)

Hope this will helpfull for you.

Comment: A bit difficult to setup (at least on Ubuntu 14.04) but very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I had big problems with iwdp. Didn't worked properly for me. But i figured it out :)

**BrowserSync** debugger was a bull's-eye :)
Anyway I don't like safari at this point :D